# JPQL Select Entity and Get count on collection that belongs to selected entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got an entity A with a collection of B elements.

I would like to create a query that basically does this:

```
Select a, count(b) from A a  inner join fetch a.b b group by a
```

I was hoping to get an Array Object where element 0 is my A entity and element 1 is a Number which is the number in the collection.

Jpa (backed by hibernate) throws the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Not in aggregate function or group by clause:   org.hsqldb.Expression@16d829b1 in statement (sql query)
```

When i copy and paste the native sql from the error into postgres, it doesn't work.

When i copy and paste the native sql from the following JPQL query:

```
Select a, count(b) from A a  inner join fetch a.b b group by a, b
```

Postgres returns the expected results. The problem is Hibernate still coughs up the same error as the first Query.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense. If you group by a, b, the count will obviously be 1, since every [a, b] row will be distinct from all the other ones. That said, even if you fix your query, you'll be butten by https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1615

Comment: That bug does look like what I'm running into, but Zaroual Mohamed's query does work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, a.b.size FROM A a INNER JOIN FETCH a.b b
```

Comment: that basically works, but if I have 2 A's one with 1 B and one with 4 Bs,  I get 5 Objects returned. The first 4 all looks like 
    Object[]{A, 4} and the last one looks like Object[]{B, 1}

Comment: i edited the query. please try the new version and tell us if it works :)

Comment: it's so simple, you have 5 B's and you are quering A joining all B's, so you got 5 rows. To eliminate duplicates you add ''DISTINCT' keyword .